# jquery toggle show/hide alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I added Jquery toggle/show hide in my site (click the plus sign)
http://pligg.marsgibson.info
if you see at my jquery its a bit jerky that is when plus is clicked all the text below it move to right when comes down 
see the jquery effect in this site 
http://oxytheme.com/Interface 
whats the difference b/w the two its the style or jquery itself?
I want the jquery just like in second site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `slideToggle`, instead of `toggle`.

[toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) affects both `width` and `height`, [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) only `height`.